# Passing UseState in React Native with typescript to Input box component and updating it onChange

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, onchange, react-native-textinput

I am having some problems passing the use state to a custom text input component.I want to update the state of symbol everytime a user makes a change in the input box. The use state symbol does not get updated and come back as undefined.

**App.tsx**

```
    const App = () => {
    
    const [symbol, setSymbol] = useState('AMD');
    
    
       function handleSymbolChange() {
        setSymbol(symbol);
      }
    
    return (
    <View>
      <AppTextInput placeholder="Symbol" icon="activity" value={symbol} 
      onTextInputChange= {handleSymbolChange}/>
    </View>
  );
};
    }
```

**AppTextInput.tsx**

```
 interface Props {
      icon: string;
      placeholder: string;
      value: string;
      onTextInputChange: any;

}

    const AppTextInput: React.FC<Props> = ({
      icon,
      placeholder,
      value,
      onTextInputChange,
    }) => {
     
       const handleChange = (e: any) => {
        onTextInputChange(e.target.value);
        console.log(e.target.value);
      };
    
      return (
        <View>
            <Icon name={icon} size={20}/>
     
          <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            placeholder={placeholder}
            value={value}
            onChange={handleChange}
          />
        </View>
      );
    };
```

Comment: `onTextInputChange` is passing back a value, `e.target.value`, but you aren't using that value in your `handleSymbolChange` callback. You should probably change your `handleSymbolChange` function to something like this: `function handleSymbolChange(value: string) { setSymbol(value); }`

Comment: Ahh that makes sense! However I tried it and its still coming back undefined hmm

Comment: The other problem is that you're using the argument of `onChange` callback in the `TextInput` property wrong. I will write an answer on how to fix it, as it will be easier to read it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 reasons why your code isn't working as expected.

The first reason is that `onTextInputChange` is passing back a value, `e.target.value` but you aren't using that value in your `handleSymbolChange` callback. You should probably change your `handleSymbolChange` function to something like this:

```
function handleSymbolChange(value: string) {
  setSymbol(value);
}
```

The second reason is that you're not using the `e` argument of the `onChange` `TextInput` callback correctly. If you take a look at the docs, you will see that the [`onChange`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchange) callback expects an object with the following properties: `{ nativeEvent: { eventCount, target, text} }` as an argument, whereas you're using `e.target.value`. In order for it to work, you'll need to change it to something like this:

```
import {
  NativeSyntheticEvent,
  TextInput,
  TextInputChangeEventData,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const handleChange = ({
    nativeEvent: { text },
  }: NativeSyntheticEvent<TextInputChangeEventData>) => {
    onTextInputChange(text);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput onChange={handleChange} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Or use the [`onChangeText`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#onchangetext) property instead:

```
import { TextInput, View } from 'react-native';

const App = () => {
  const handleChange = (text: string) => {
    onTextInputChange(text);
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TextInput onChangeText={handleChange} />
    </View>
  );
};
```